# What is the best Jquery DataTable option?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I was using DataTables as my Jquery Table solution.  But it keeps giving me an error, for what is I believe, an unjustified reason.  So I am looking to try a different solution.  Do you know of the best up-to-date, free Jquery DataTable solutions?  The only requirement is that the solution must be able to convert an already existing HTML table into a Jquery DataTable... For various reasons, passing JSON data to the view would be just hard.  I mean, there are links in some of the rows, and it would just be hard...

But if you have any recommendations I would appreciate it.

Comment: AFAIK, DataTables is capable of reading a DOM table as the data source. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I keep getting this warning...
DataTables warning (table id = 'table1'): requested unknown parameter 0 from the data source for row 1
and some weird error with cloneNode... dude, I am just sick of dealing with it.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, you should solve the problem you have with DataTables (perhaps with the help from SO), rather than just discard this library all together. With your attitude, you may end up discarding libraries one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/dom.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body id="dt_example">
        <div id="demo">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>

        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>

    </tr>
....
```

Comment: Technically it would be easy to do ^^^^^ like what you have above.  In fact, I did it just like that.  However, I am getting an exception that I have know idea what it is, and I didn't change anything, and I am just sick of dealing with it, and there lousy help too.  I know I didn't kick any cash there way, but I am broker than a joke right now and I can't really afford to throw around too much cash.  I just want something that works and that just pulls a table out of the DOM.